# netbeans ide 6.9.1 didnt recognize jar

Tags: java, netbeans-6.9

I add a jar to my library what i have to do to have the program recognize the classes?

> **--download package.jar--**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add said jar to the classpath.

If you have a standard java application, right click the project > properties > libraries > add library at compile and runtime.

Comment: I add  DownloadServlet.jar but it marked me  <extends HttpServlet>what i have to do?